# Sendmail PAM authentication not working

Tags: pam, sendmail

I have been trying to migrate my mail functionality to a new server. I've copied my alterations to `sendmail.mc` and rebuilt `sendmail.cf`. For authentication I use a DB file that is configured in `/etc/pam.d/smtp`. I have copied this file from my old server to my new server so the usernames and passwords should be the same. When I try to connect to the new password is rejected. I have confirmed this the server by connecting manually with `openssl s_client`. If I connect to the old server I can authenicate but on the new server I cannot.

As my old server is running Ubuntu 16.04 still and the new server is 18.04 I assume it has something to do with a default configuration change between version but I'm at a dead end trying to seek it out.

Comment: Curious about the choice of sendmail. Most orgs switched to exim or postfix 10-15 years ago.

Comment: Seemed to be most easy to set up/common in forums when I was researching to switch from hMailServer some number of years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Sendmail does not use PAM directly. Sendmail uses saslauthd which then in turn uses PAM to authenticate. With this in mind I then tried to authenticate using `testsaslauthd - s smtp -u [myusername] -p [mypassword]` only to receive the error `connect() : No such file or directory 0`

On my new server I had not updated `/etc/default/saslauthd` to set `START=yes`. I did this and restarted the service and my server works.